# The multi-part identifier could not be bound - stuff cmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting a Stuff Cmd to combine multiple rows to a single entry.  I keep getting "The multi-part identifier "SPCLT.CD_VAL_DESC" could not be bound." (under the first SELECT statement)

```
STUFF(
    (SELECT
        **',' + SPCLT.CD_VAL_DESC**
    FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            SPCLT.CD_VAL_DESC SPECIALTY
    FROM  PIN_STATUS PS

    INNER JOIN PROV_TYPE_SPCLT SPC
        ON PS.PROV_ID = SPC.PROV_ID
        AND SPC.VLDT_IND = 'Y'

    INNER JOIN CODE_REF SPCLT
    ON SPC.SPCLT_CD = SPCLT.CD_VAL
    AND SPCLT.CD_REF_NM = 'SPECIALTY'
    AND SPCLT.VLDT_IND = 'Y'

WHERE SPC.VLDT_IND = 'Y'
) SPCLTY 
    for xml 
                    path('')
                )
                ,1,1,'') SPECIALTIES
```

Comment: It should `SPCLTY .SPECIALTY` since you aliased `CD_VAL_DESC` in the subquery.

Comment: First, which DBMS is this?  I assume MS SQL Server, but you must confirm.  Secondly, in SQL Server, `STUFF` is a function and not a command.  You appear to be trying to use it as a command, which would explain your problem.

Comment: I thought that at first too, but I still get the same error.  
The multi-part identifier "SPCLT.SPECIALTY" could not be bound.

Comment: Yes SQL Server - I've done these type of stuffs previously and gotten them to work, I was actually trying to tweak a previously used code, but I'm not sure what is different on this one.

Comment: @Christy Felix Pamittan already gave you the answer you need

Comment: I hate when people refer to this as the `STUFF` method/cmd/whatever, because it means people are just applying it rote with no understanding whatsoever. It's the misuse of the `FOR XML` functionality together with empty element names that performs the concatenation, to produce a string like `,a,b,c,d`. All that `STUFF` actually does, here, is remove the leading comma.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay attention to the format of your SQL, and then the answer would probably jump out and bite you on the nose... happens to everyone.

Your query:

```
STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
        ',' + SPCLT.CD_VAL_DESC
    FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            SPCLT.CD_VAL_DESC SPECIALTY
        FROM  PIN_STATUS PS

        INNER JOIN PROV_TYPE_SPCLT SPC
            ON PS.PROV_ID = SPC.PROV_ID
            AND SPC.VLDT_IND = 'Y'

        INNER JOIN CODE_REF SPCLT
            ON SPC.SPCLT_CD = SPCLT.CD_VAL
            AND SPCLT.CD_REF_NM = 'SPECIALTY'
            AND SPCLT.VLDT_IND = 'Y'

        WHERE SPC.VLDT_IND = 'Y'
        ) SPCLTY 
    for xml path('')
    )
,1,1,'') SPECIALTIES
```

...is divided into sub-queries.  The `STUFF()` function is acting on the first `SELECT` beneath it.

That first `SELECT` is taking data `FROM` a sub-query, which has been aliased as `SPCLTY`.  So, naturally, within that `SELECT`, you need to be referencing `SPCLTY` and not `SPCLT`.

Adding a bit of whitespace makes it a little clearer, I think.